# Replace unknown inductor

Tags: inductor

I have a PCB board from my washing machine which has an faulty inductor (marked as L4) on it. This inductor is in all probability used to limit the current on the Vdd of a series of ICs.

Now its a 0805 SMD package without any coding and any documentation on the PCB is not available.

I was wondering if anyone could advice me with what kind of inductance value I should replace the faulty inductor with? The available values for these case dimensions range from 560nH to 330uH.

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: The limited information only allows highly speculative answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductor is unlikely to be limiting the current to the ICs, but it may be keeping their noise out of the power supply, or keeping supply noise away from the ICs, perhaps to reduce RF emissions.

As such the actual inductance would not be especially critical, but the DC resistance of the replacement should be similar to the original. Can you measure that? If the failure is such that you can't, your options are:

- keep looking for documentation on the machine (Google and persistence)
- Find a replacement board (eBay is your friend ... sometimes)
- Find a second machine and measure the resistance of it's inductor
- if there's an identical looking L on the existing board, assume it's the same and measure that
- guess ( and go for something reasonable like <1 ohm series resistance)

EDIT:
[This link](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203354%20110131825%20110234488%20110131855%20110197193%20110153254%20110268174%20110182704%20110159362%20110121292%20110519534&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203354%20110131825%20110234488%20110131855%20110197193%20110153254%20110268174%20110182704%20110159362%20110121292&mm=1002362%7C110131825%7C110121292,1002192%7C%7C,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=203354&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=203354) shows 6 candidates from Farnell with 0805 package and 0.7 to 0.8 ohm resistance. Inductances cover quite a range, you may narrow it down by comparing with yours. In any case, I think yours will probably work, subject to its current rating being greater than the current draw you measure through it.

Comment: The resistance is 265 ohm, way high, likely because of the damage. I searched for a indentical L on the board, and measured that, which resulted in .75 ohm. Seems better... If I check with my supplier that means a inductance of 3.9uH, sounds good?

Comment: 0.75R and 3.9uh sounds plausible at any rate. Same resistance from a different manufacturer will be a different L, but probably in the same ballpark. May be slightly outside emissions regs, but should work. Also: measure the current through it in operation (or V across it) and compare that with its rated current.

Comment: The voltage across is 5V. But 5/.75 results in 6.66A. Isn't that a bit much? Maybe I'm doing something wrong, my ohms law knowledge is a bit rusty.

Comment: No, you won't drop 5V across the inductor unless the ICs are a dead short circuit. In which case you have bigger problems! :-) If you put the inductor in and measure (say) 0.1V drop across it, that means 0.1V/0.75R = 133ma. In fact you could use a suitable resistor (say 1 ohm) for this test if you haven't an inductor. That will tell you if you need a higher current inductor.